# How can I prevent the re-rendering of my component when updating the useState value in a custom React hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a custom hook, which returns an array with 2 elements:

- a component, containing an input
- and a function, which is in charge of checking the value of input

Simple! Apparently...

But I can't get the component not to be re-rerendered every time the value of the "useState" is updated. And that takes the focus off the input.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const useCustomHook = () => {
  const [textoDelInput, settextoDelInput] = useState('');

  const validarTexto = () => {
    return textoDelInput !== '';
  };

  const InputComponent = () => {
    const handleChange = (event) => {
      settextoDelInput(event.target.value);
    };

    return <input type="text" value={textoDelInput} onChange={handleChange} />;
  };

  return [validarTexto, InputComponent];
};

export default useCustomHook;
```

My real code is more complex and long, but, it's the same principle.

[Reproduction of the example, in a playground here](https://playcode.io/1484404)

In my basic example, the problem could be solved with "useRef", but not in my real code. Because I don't always have the possibility to pass a reference to the "input", since they are components of external libraries.

Could you guide me on why this happens? Please, and give me ideas on what I could try to solve it.

Thank you!

Comment: actually it's defining different `InputComponent` inside the hook makes field to lose the focus on re-rendering. Not re-rendering itself. You see, whatever component gets this `InputComponent` from hook's return value and renders, it will be _referentially_ different(e.g. just like if you switch from `input` to `textarea` or `span`) so React unmounts previous component and mounts new one

Comment: hard to suggest something until you describe _your goal_, not the way you tried to go for it. Why do you want to return component definition from the hook in the first place? what do you really need?

Comment: Thanks for answer @skyboyer!
But, I don't quite understand what you mean by defining different "InputComponent". Could you explain a little more what you mean? please.

In general, this is a simplified example of what I needed to do at the time. A hook that returns a component and various functions to interact with the component's data.

My goal is to be able to make a hook, which allows me to create a component with several fields (input, textarea, select...), and also return functions to, for example, check if the form has all the fields filled out.

Comment: The original problem for which I posted my post was already solved, simply by changing the focus to use a simple component.
But, I have the doubt of knowing how it would be the correct way to do it, and why it loses focus that way.

Comment: you are declaring component right in the hook body. Each time host component(a component with this hook) re-renders, hooks re-runs and returns [_referentially_ different](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) `InputComponent`. Since component is referentially difference, React does not update existing `<InputComponent ...` with different props but instead _deletes existing_ instance and creates new one. Which makes focus to go away.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your explanation @skyboyer!

I found that "useImperativeHandle" can change the approach to do something very similar to what I was looking for with the custom hook in the first place.